# What does "dary" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/sjdxUiAJ0UQ). It is at 5 minute and 34 second.

> Finally, make your speech legend -- wait for it -- **dary** by telling a great story.

Comment: FWIW, it's *lege**n** – wait for it – dary*.

Comment: I believe this is from "How I Met Your Mother" and I wouldn't expect to see it anywhere else, or be used in general conversation. Only really as a quote from the series.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dqf1BmN4Dag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She says:

> legen -- wait for it -- dary

if you snip *-- wait for it --* out, you get *legen [ ] dary* or:

> legendary

She is actually saying:

> Finally, make your speech **legendary** by telling a great story.